# C# .net 4.5: Generic class inheriting from List with a where constraint

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.5

Working on a big project, I realized the following snippet :

```
public interface Mother 
{
    void CoolFeature();
}

public interface Daughter : Mother 
{
}

public class YouJustLostTheGame<T> : List<T> where T : Mother 
{
    public void Crowd(Mother item) 
    {
       this.Add(item); 
    }

    public void useFeature() 
    {
       this.Find(a => { return true; }).CoolFeature(); 
    }
}
```

fails to compile the `Crowd(Mother)` function with the message "Unable to convert 'Test.Mother' to 'T'".
Of course this seems deeply wrong to me, and the `useFeature()` is perfectly fine.
So what am I missing ?

N.B: VS2012, win7 x64, .NET 4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it doesn't compile is because it cannot work. Consider

```
public class MotherClass : Mother
{
    // ...
}

public class DaughterClass : Daughter
{
    // ...
}

void breakThings()
{
    new YouJustLostTheGame<Daughter>().Crowd(new MotherClass());
}
```

`YouJustLostTheGame<Daughter>` derives from `List<Daughter>`. `List<Daughter>` can only store `Daughter`s. Your `Crowd` takes a `Mother` as its parameter, so `new MotherClass()` is a valid argument. It then attempts to store an item in the list that the list isn't capable of holding.

Comment: Wow, silly me. That's so obvious once explained. Thanks for cleaning up my friday confusion !

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the method signature to accept T instead of mother. crowd(T item)....